# how to change multiple squares color all in once?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to change 6 squares colors all in once and each with a different color.

```
function randomNum() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}
function randomRGB() {
  var red = randomNum();
  var green = randomNum();
  var blue = randomNum();
  return [red,green,blue];
}
```

I have this JavaScript code that generates  random RGB colors values. How can I make it so that each square gets a random color each time I refresh? I can do it with 6 lines of code, but I'm trying to learn easier ways to code. If anyone can do it in a simpler code, I would be grateful!

[image: PintSreen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is reasonably short and quite readable. Consider sticking with it.

Alternatives include

- Using (and immediately returning) `Array.from` with `randomNum` as a mapper function to construct an array with 3 random values
- Using arrow functions for concise return

```js
const randomNum = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
const randomRGB = () => Array.from({ length: 3 }, randomNum);

console.log(randomRGB());
```

If you want to do this 6 times, then you might use another `Array.from`.

```js
const randomNum = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
const randomRGB = () => Array.from({ length: 3 }, randomNum);
const randomSquares = numSquares => Array.from({ length: numSquares }, randomRGB);

console.log(randomSquares(6));
```

Comment: thank you for the note, but how do I change 6 different squares colors all in ones, and randomly generated colors?

Comment: // $(".2").css("background-color","rgb("+color2+")");
i'm using this way to change colors each time, I typed it 6 times, but I'm looking for a easier way...

Comment: Use a single class for each square, and then you can iterate over the squares and call `randomRGB` for each. Without seeing the actual code you're using, hard to be more specific.

Comment: thank you, i solved it this way, if you please can tell me if that's good enough for a beginner I would appreciate it!  *iam not that good with using Stack overflow yet , sorry for the messed up code comment
var randColors=randomSquares(6);
for(var i=0;i<=7;i++){
    $("."+i).css("background-color","rgb("+randColors[i]+")");

}

Comment: Like I said, better to use a single class for the squares (you can iterate over them with `.each`) - that's nicer than hard-coding the `randomSquares(6)` and the `i <= 7`

Comment: i'm still new to all of this, I'm watching a course on udemy which teached me to type it like that, I'll try to give them a single class, and use .each instead, idk how it really works , but I'll do my research, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply grid a six digit hexadecimal number and then use them for your color.
Like the following number for example: `#ffffff` (which is white)

```
function random hexColor() {
   return ((Math.random() * 0xfffff * 1000000).toString(16)).slice(0,6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach: use the [**hsl()** color function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl) and generate a random [**Hue color**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_wheel) (from 0 to 360)

```js
const rand = (min, max) => ~~(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

document.querySelectorAll(".grid > div").forEach(elBox => {
  elBox.style.background = `hsl(${rand(0, 360)}, 100%, 50%)`;
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.grid > * {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

The nice thing about it is that you only change the Hue (color), but the saturation and lightness remain the same for all your elements.

Example with desaturated, darker colors:

```js
const rand = (min, max) => ~~(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

document.querySelectorAll(".grid > div").forEach(elBox => {
  elBox.style.background = `hsl(${rand(0, 360)}, 70%, 30%)`;
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.grid > * {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Eventually you can generate also a random value in range for the Lightness and Saturation (0 to 100 %)